# extracting column names from a csv file in R

Tags: r, null, names

I am completely new to this so my question is going to be really basic.

I am extracting the column names of a csv file and what I get is NULL:

> names("thm.csv")
>   NULL

Can someone tell me why and how should I extract the names?
Thanks..

Comment: The "csv file" is ... where? On disk?  or have your already read it into R?

Answer (score 0):

At first you should get your thm.csv into R.
Therefore set your working directory to a local folder 
e.g. "C:\Users\Alonso\Documents\Alonsos.project"

```
setwd("C:/Users/your.name/Documents/your.project")
```

now copy your file "thm.csv" into the directory

```
df <- read.csv2("thm.csv")
names(df)
```

this should extract the names for you.